# Changing a private member variable does not affect the whole class

Tags: c++

I have a class, in it is a `private` member variable called which is an `int`. For some reason, if I change its value in a method (on the constructor, for example), it will change just fine. But if I change it on a different method and use `printf` to output what its contents are on yet another different method, the value is not carried over and is changed into a very very large number.

Header:

```
class Fruit {
   private:
      int m_fruitState; // 0 = IDLE, 1 = GROWING, 2 = READY, 3 = FALLEN, 4 = ROTTEN
      int m_fruitTimer;

    public:
       Fruit ( );

       int getFruitState( ); // Returns m_fruitState
       void setFruitState( int fState );

       void growFruit( CCTime dt ); // Called every 1 second (CCTime is a cocos2d-x class)
    };
```

CPP

```
#include "Fruit.h"

Fruit::Fruit( ) {
   // Set other member variables
   this -> setFruitState( 0 );  // m_fruitState = 0
   this -> m_fruitTimer = 0;
   this -> m_fruitSprite -> schedule( schedule_selector( Fruit::growFruit ), 1.0 ); // m_fruitSprite is a CCSprite (a cocos2d-x class). This basically calls growFruit() every 1 second
}

int getFruitState( ) {
   return this -> m_fruitState;
}

void setFruitState( int state ) {
   this -> m_fruitState = state;
}

void growFruit( CCTime dt ) {
   this -> m_fruitTimer++;
   printf( "%d seconds have elapsed.", m_fruitTimer );
   printf( "STATE = %d", this -> m_fruitState ); // Says my m_fruitState is a very big number

   // This if condition never becomes true, because at this point, m_fruitState = a very big number
   if ( this -> getfruitState( ) == 0 ) { // I even changed this to m_fruitState == 0, still the same
      if ( this -> m_fruitTimer == 5 ) { // check if 5 seconds have elapsed
         this -> setFruitState( 1 );
         this -> m_fruitTimer = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

And then on the main, I make an instance of MyClass.

I have no idea why that happens. Why does C++ do that and how do I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you call your methods? Show `main()`.

Comment: Can you post the code that causes `doSomething()` to print that number? Also, why should it be 5?! What is this `newInt`?

Comment: The code is invalid. Post real code.

Comment: What compiler are you using? This works fine for me.

Comment: Post your `main` function. By the way, you can remove the `this ->`.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck: I'm using Xcode and cocos2d-x library. I don't think cocos2d-x would actually affect my class since it is a custom class and they are member variables I have written myself.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In the main, I just make an instance of MyClass (`MyClass myObject = MyClass( );`) and I keep the `this ->` for readability (I kinda got used to it).

Comment: Is this the _exact_ code you have? It works fine for me. What compiler and OS are you using?

Comment: Okay, I'll try to post the code I'm writing. @SingerOfTheFall Xcode and Mac OS (dunno which version though, I'm a Windows guy, I was just forced to use a Mac)

Comment: Could it be that you haven't built the latest version and you are running an executable that doesn't correspond to the code you are showing?

Comment: @AndreasBrinck: If you fix his code, you destroy the question. The question asks what the issues with the code are. If you fix the code in the question, there's no question left. (Or, at least, a different question.) If the missing semi-colon was causing code after the #include of the header file to be misinterpreted causing the issue the OP was asking about, the question becomes incoherent.

Comment: Edited to make it closer to what I'm doing.

Comment: Instead of making it closer, post what you're actually doing.

Comment: You've completely changed the question for the third time. And the code still makes no sense. For example, `growFruit` is not a member function but accesses a `this` pointer. And `mFruitSprite` comes out of nowhere. We really need to see the real code to debug it. Can you post a complete, compilable program (with `main` and everything) that demonstrates the *actual* problem you are having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "selector" argument to `schedule` should be a `SEL_SCHEDULE`, where

```
typedef void(CCObject::* SEL_SCHEDULE)(float)
```

i.e it should be a member function of a `CCObject`.
It is also supposed to be a member of the object you call `schedule` *on*, otherwise the target when it's called will be wrong.

I suspect that this

```
this -> m_fruitSprite -> schedule( schedule_selector( Fruit::growFruit ), 1.0 );
```

causes a call to `Fruit::growFruit` with `this` pointing at the *sprite*, not the fruit, which leads to all kinds of unpleasantness.
(Note that `schedule_selector` does a C-style cast, which means that it's inherently unsafe. Don't use it.)

Comment: Yep, now that he shows us something closer to the actual code, the error is more obvious. He isn't calling that function on a valid member of his class.

Comment: `this` on the `this -> m_fruitSprite -> schedule( schedule_selector( Fruit::growFruit ), 1.0 );` refers to the `Fruit` object. Meaning, the `m_fruitSprite` (which is a CCSprite object) is part of the `Fruit` object. I was wrong on using `schedule` outside of the main layer, got around it by over-riding the `update()` method of the main layer and making an `updateFruit()` method on the `Fruit` class instead. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
     changeInt( int newInt );       // Assume newInt = 5
```

Remove the `int` from the above line.

```
  void doSomething( ); {
```

Remove the `;` from the above line.

**Update:** Now you're missing a `;` from the end of the header file. Fixing all the obvious bugs (that would likely keep it from even compiling), it works fine for me. Either there's still a difference between the code you pasted and the real code, or you've found a compiler bug.

```
Constructor: myInt = 0
changeInt( int ) : myInt = 5
After constructor and calling changeInt(), myInt = 5
```

Comment: Where is he missing a `;`? oO

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: At the end of the header file.

Comment: If you mean the one in the end of the class, it's there. And his copy-pasted code works for me too.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Someone just modified it.